# Error deleting first column in CListCtrl

Tags: mfc, clistctrl

I am generating a CListCtrl in Report view (MFC). It loads fine and I can reorder columns by dragging the headers. I've made it so clicking a column header deletes the column - again this works fine except for the first (leftmost) column. Here the header is deleted but the data underneath doesn't change - in fact the data from the last column is deleted:

Before :

```
Header1    Header2     Header3

 Data1      Data2       Data3
```

After trying to delete first column :

```
Header2     Header3

 Data1       Data2
```

Having created the columns to begin with, I'm setting up the rest of       the table like this:

```
void MyClass::InsertItem(int x, int y, CString &str)
{

    LVITEM lvi;
    lvi.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
    lvi.iItem = y;
    lvi.iSubItem = x;
    lvi.pszText = (LPTSTR)(LPCTSTR)(str);
    int result;
    if(x == 0)    {
        result = mCSVListCtrl.InsertItem(&lvi); 
    }
    else {
        result = mCSVListCtrl.SetItem(&lvi); 
    }
}
```

which seems to create the table OK. Then when a header is clicked:

```
void MyClass::OnLvnColumnclickList(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMLISTVIEW pNMLV = reinterpret_cast<LPNMLISTVIEW>(pNMHDR);

    mCSVListCtrl.DeleteColumn(pNMLV->iSubItem);// This IS getting zero

    *pResult = 0;
}
```

Comment: Show us code. Seams that you just deleted the column from the header control not from the list view!

Comment: It's definitely the CListCtrl I'm trying to delete from. Still puzzled - must be something to do with the difference between an item and a subitem?

Answer (score 0):

Without any code it is complicated to find a reason.

I suppose you used `CListCtrl::GetHeaderCtrl::DeleteItem`.

You have to use `CListCtrl::DeleteColumn`